# How to add images with figure captions to a word document

Tags: python, vba, ms-word, pywin32, caption

```
import win32com.client as win32
import os

#creating a word application object
wordApp = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application') #create a word application object
wordApp.Visible = True # hide the word application
doc = wordApp.Documents.Add() # create a new application

#Formating the document
doc.PageSetup.RightMargin = 10
doc.PageSetup.LeftMargin = 10
doc.PageSetup.Orientation = win32.constants.wdOrientLandscape
# a4 paper size: 595x842
doc.PageSetup.PageWidth = 595
doc.PageSetup.PageHeight = 842


# Inserting Tables
my_dir="C:/Users/David/Documents/EGi/EGi Plots/FW_plots/Boxplots"
filenames = os.listdir(my_dir)
piccount=0
file_count = 0
for i in filenames:
    if i[len(i)-3: len(i)].upper() == 'JPG': # check whether the current object is a JPG file
        piccount = piccount + 1

print piccount, " images will be inserted"

total_column = 1
total_row = int(piccount/total_column)+2
rng = doc.Range(0,0)
rng.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = win32.constants.wdAlignParagraphCenter
table = doc.Tables.Add(rng,total_row, total_column)
table.Borders.Enable = False
if total_column > 1:
    table.Columns.DistributeWidth()

#Collecting images in the same directory and inserting them into the document


piccount = 1

for index, filename in enumerate(filenames): # loop through all the files and folders for adding pictures

    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(my_dir), filename)): # check whether the current object is a file or not
        if filename[len(filename)-3: len(filename)].upper() == 'JPG': # check whether the current object is a JPG file
            piccount = piccount + 1
            print filename, len(filename), filename[len(filename)-3: len(filename)].upper()


            cell_column = (piccount % total_column + 1) #calculating the position of each image to be put into the correct table cell
            cell_row = (piccount/total_column + 1)
            #print 'cell_column=%s,cell_row=%s' % (cell_column,cell_row)

            #we are formatting the style of each cell
            cell_range= table.Cell(cell_row, cell_column).Range
            cell_range.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = win32.constants.wdLineSpaceSingle
            cell_range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 0
            cell_range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 3

            #this is where we are going to insert the images
            current_pic=cell_range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(my_dir), filename))


            #Currently this puts a lable in a cell after the pic, I want to put a proper ms word figure caption below the image instead.
            table.Cell(cell_row, cell_column).Range.InsertAfter("\n"+"Appendix II Figure "+ str(piccount-1)+": "+filename[:len(filename)-4]+"\n"+"\n"+"\n")


        else: continue
```

This code gets all the images in a chosen directory and puts them in a table in a word doc, and then puts the file name (stripped of the file extn) in the cell below.  I would like a proper figure caption (so that these will update if I insert additional pictures) but everything I've tried has failed.

I just can't get the VB commands right, this:

```
table.Cell(cell_row, cell_column).Range.InsertAfter(InsertCaption(Label="Figure", Title=": "+filename[:len(filename)-4]))
```

gives me a list of figure captions at the end of the document, which isn't really what I want. I feel like I am close but I just cant quite get it. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `current_pic.InsertCaption`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.insertcaption

Comment: @najeem yes I get the following: AttributeError: '<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library.InlineShape instance at 0x1245537160>' object has no attribute 'InsertCaption'

Comment: @flashliquid See: http://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/16772-4-digital-images-1-page.html#post47919

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use Word's built-in captioning instead of `current_pic.InsertCaption` use `current_Pic.Range.InsertCaption`. The `InsertCaption` method is a member of the `Range` not the `InlineShape` object. For me, this automatically inserts the caption below the picture, in its own paragraph. But if you want to specificy "below" use the `Position` argument, as well:

```
current_pic.Range.InsertCaption(Label="Figure", Title=": "+filename[:len(filename)-4]), Position=win32.constants.wdCaptionPositionBelow
```

*Note: FWIW when I test the line of code (in VBA) that you say gives you a list of captions at the end of the document I do see the text in the same cell as the inserted picture.*

Comment: Thanks Cindy Meister, I had been pulling my hair out over this and found the VBA docs quite impenetrable,  and obs now feel quite silly. Thanks for the solution, does exactly what I want (and didn't need the position part). Cheers!